# Why doesn't linting in Github Actions work when it does locally?

Tags: go, github-actions

I'm building a Go project, and i'm using Github actions on every checkin.

The project is here: https://github.com/filecoin-project/bacalhau

When I run the project locally, it runs fine - e.g.:

```sh
❯ golangci-lint run
❯
```

But when I do the same command in Github Actions, I get warnings like I haven't vendored in the modules correctly (guessing).

```
  Error: undeclared name: `libp2p` (typecheck)
  Error: undeclared name: `libp2p` (typecheck)
  Error: undeclared name: `libp2p` (typecheck)
  Error: "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p" imported but not used (typecheck)
  
  Error: issues found
```

Even when I remove the linting, I get similar problems (it doesn't build properly - e.g. https://github.com/filecoin-project/bacalhau/runs/5313987141?check_suite_focus=true

The *ONE* time I logged in myself, via ssh, and executed the build manually (e.g. `go build`) it failed with the same error, but this was solveable by just doing `go mod vendor`, `go mod tidy` inline. HOWEVER, this shouldn't be necessary, right? Because I've checked in a vendor directory?

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Go is your pipeline using? The link to the run you posted has the line `imports github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/qtls: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/runner/work/bacalhau/bacalhau/vendor/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/qtls` in it. It looks like if you use a version of Go before 1.16, this will happen. I bet locally you have a newer version while the pipeline is using 1.11 <= x <= 1.15.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's not that. The github page for the docker image says it defaults to latest: https://github.com/wangyoucao577/go-release-action#parameters

Comment: i thought the same - but go is the same everywhere - 1.17.6.

I also was able to repro it working on my mac, which is a totally different go version. It only doesn't work in Github actions.

Comment: My next step would be to run `go env` in both environments and compare. I'm not sure exactly what you'd be looking for, but I bet that'll shed some light.

Comment: It's a 100% match - that was my first thought too.

Comment: If running `go mod vendor` or `go mod tidy` fixes the build, then perhaps your vendor folder is incomplete? If your local env is one OS but the build env is a different OS then build constraints could result in a vendor folder that is only complete for a particular OS (I think, I haven't run into this myself but it seems possible). A simple check would be to run `GOOS=x GOARCH=y go mod vendor` locally with values that match your build environment and see if it downloads anything new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by blowing away everything in my /vendor dir, and .gitignoring it. This forced GitHub actions to redownload everything. Not sure if this was the most efficient solution, but worked for me!